# Can the following conditional value be expressed using the min and max functions?

Tags: notation

For example, consider $y$ such that
$$
y=\cases{c, & if $c\le0$,\\0, & if $c>0$.}
$$
Then, it can be easily expressed as $$y=\min\{c, 0\}.$$

---

Using the above trick, can I express the following $y$ using $\max$ or $\min$ ?
$$
y = \cases{c, & if $c\le d$,\\ 0, & if $c>d$.}$$

Comment: $\max$ and $\min$ are continuous functions, whereas your function is not continuous. So there is no obvious solution that I can see.

Comment: @TonyK Your brief answer gave me a lot of knowledge. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second function is discontinuous, you will need an extra "step" term, like

$$y=\min\{c-d,0\}+d\cdot(c\le d).$$

If you don't mind having an undefined value at $c=d$, you can "emulate" with

$$y=\min\{c-d,0\}\frac c{c-d}.$$

Comment: Actually, I wanted to make it using max or min or both, but I knew that it is impossible. Thank you for proposing another way to make it.